# how to open windows explorer with search result from python

Tags: python, windows, shell, command-line, windows-explorer

I have created a File indexer and searcher script in python which indexes all files which could be used later for fast search .

I want to open the search result in windows explorer . I know **subprocess.Popen(r'explorer /select,"C:\path\of\folder\file")** this command execution will open a specified directory . I have also read

- https://support.microsoft.com/en-us/help/314853/explorer-exe-command-line-options-for-windows-xp
- https://answers.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/forum/windows_7-performance/windows-7-explorerexe-command-line-switches/ad7242df-566a-4378-913c-920393f6e674?auth=1

**How to do it ??**

Comment: Don't expect people to follow a bunch of offsite links. Tell us what you found there that's relevant instead.

Comment: I dont have idea how to open multiple files from the search reult to open in a single explorer window

Comment: Add that to your question by clicking on the edit button just below the tags. People should be able to read your question and understand what you are asking without having to read comments. Comments should be for clarification of details, not for posing the actual question.

Comment: @MadPhysicist The question is quite clear for me. OP wants to show a list of files in an explorer window, similar to how explorer shows a search result. The difference is that he wants to show a list of files that his python script generated.

Comment: @zett42. I understand what OP is trying to achieve, approximately, but OP also seems to know how to do it. I am not sure what the actual problem is.

Comment: @MadPhysicist The links OP provided show his research but don't provide a solution.